# Show navigation bar when in split view in Word for Mac 2016

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In Word for Mac 2016, showing the navigation bar when in split view removes the split view. Is there a way to maintain the split view when showing the navigation bar? Alternatively, is there a way to jump to a specific section when in split view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on my system. Make sure your version is fully updated. Are you running a subscription version? If not, and after updating, if it still does not work it might be related to not having a subscription version.

[image]

Comment: Updating solved issue